# How to create "lichtenstein" hair strokes quickly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing

Is there an easy and fast way to create strokes like shown in the image? I think about drawing one white stroke on a black shape and use some effect and/or some sort of transformation?

[image]

Comment: I don't get what you want a single stroke to look like. Could you maybe edit the screenshot to draw in a blue line or something where the pen would be in your example?

Comment: I just sketched it and posted in chat trying to figure it out with someone as far as where you mean for the pen to be: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31754856#31754856

Comment: well, I don't mind how many path are there, as long as the results looks like this. I just figured it will be an awfull lot of work to draw every single stroke with the pen.